# unsplash query gives random image

Tags: javascript, node.js, fetch-api

I'm new in learning of building apps with API and node.js and stuck with a problem.
UI is updated from city.value input and when I fetch API, search query return a random img, however when I hardcode value in fetch URL the image is correct.

Help please, what I'm missing/not seeing?

```js
const city = document.getElementById('city').value;
const messageBody = document.getElementById('content');

    const postImage = new Image();
fetch(`https://api.unsplash.com/search/photos?query=${city}&client_id=${client_id}`)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(
        result => {
            const imgurl = result.results.map(
                hit => hit.urls.regular
            );
            postImage.src = imgurl[0];
            console.log(imgurl[0])
        },
        error => {
            console.log(error);
        }
    );

const updateUI = (items) => {
    let html = items.map((item => {
        return ` 
        <p> 
        ${item.content} 
        <img src='${postImage.src}' width='400'>
        </p>`;
    })).join(" ");
    messageBody.innerHTML = html;
}
```

Comment: Sounds like it's working how it should - what are you expecting the image from the API to be when it's randomly returned?

Comment: city.value doesn't work - random irrelevant image is returned - instead of city some typewriter, and it's the same img on every next user input

Comment: Oh ok, makes sense. I'd say make sure that every time user input changes, you make the `fetch` call with the new `city`. From what you've posted it's not clear whether that's happening.